# PHP web crawler, data structure and storage, Will it work with PHPCrawl?

Tags: php, web-crawler, phpcrawl

**If there are other classes written to do this, a link would be awesome. If not, how can I do it with PHPCrawl?**

Is it possible to store specific information from a crawled site based upon a set of rules specific to the site? Ex., `[div.wantThis, img#defaultPicture]` is the array returned for site A and only `[div.shortTextContent]` is the array returned for site B?

In PHPCrawl, how can I get this information out of the `$page_data` array?

**Needs**

Must be able to target only certain elements.

Able to read the data storage rule from a variable (which could be an array specifying the element(s) to target).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is how to parse specific content from site A and some other specific content from site B using PHPCrawl.

For **site specific parsing style** following if-else approach can be followed:

```
for url in urls:
    content = crawl(url)
    if(url of type 1?):
        extract_style1(content)
    else-if(url of type 2?):
        extract_style2(content)
    else:
        extract_styledefault(content)
```

For **specific content extracting** following algo can be used:
Note: *There are spectrum of parsing techniques avaliable, I am implmeneting **HTML DOM Parsing** here..*

```
// Create DOM from your PHP Crawl Data Source
$html = $page_data[source]

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

**Reference:** 
[HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
[PHPCrawl Example](http://www.crucerosprincess.com/crawler/documentation/example.html)